# Error: Could not resolve module @angular/core

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-ec2, npm, webpack

I am trying to run an angular 4 application but i keep getting this error

```
ERROR in Could not resolve module @angular/core
```

There are no other errors. No dependency errors nothing. @angular/core exists in the node_modules folder. I have tried with @angular/cli installed and without but no effect on this error. I am not sure how to resolve this. 
It occurs in my amazon ec2 machine but not in my local Mac machine. The versions of the libraries are all the same.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: can be usefule? https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20820 ? you solve it?

Comment: Which typescript version do you have ?

Comment: It sounds like your package.json is not setup correctly. Perhaps if you listed that it would shed some light. You haven't done something like put it in the devDependencies by mistake have you? I'd compare yours to some you can Google, such as this: https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/package.json and compare versions etc. and refer back to this. https://angular.io/guide/npm-packages

Answer (score 3):

If anyone still facing such issue-

Your package.json may have been corrupt. Follow the below steps:

1. Delete node_module folder.
2. Clean/clear the cache. To clear the cache, run the below command.

   `npm cache clean --force`
3. Install angular/core library again (specific version of your application).

   `npm i @angular/core`
4. Again run `npm install`

Comment: Went through these steps and ended up with the same issue.

Comment: @Franciscod'Anconia Could you solve it?

Comment: @FernandoJavierLeón  I'm sorry, I don't remember how I resolved this.

Comment: Yeah thanks. I follow this and solve the issue without step 3

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, solved changing the tsconfig, not sure that it will helps, using this now,:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": "./",
      "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "declaration": false,
      "module": "es2015",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "target": "es5",
      "typeRoots": [
        "node_modules/@types"
      ],
      "lib": [
        "es2017",
        "dom"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

What may cause such issue is caused by an incorrect TypeScript configuration.
Make sure your tsconfig.json has `moduleResolution` set to `"node"` (rather than e.g. `"classic"`).